# How to check 2 Coroutine and run simultaneously?

Tags: loops, unity-game-engine, scripting, sequence, coroutine

I'm currently building a game where the player will move based on the sequences added to the list. But it depends on 2 sequence, Sequence and inside sequence. So I use 2 `coroutine`s to differentiate both, but it does not execute the other `Coroutine` and stops the game. Can you guys tell me why? I'm still new to developing the game, so I don't know much about the syntax (I did read the manual in unity, btw). I hope you can help me.

```
public void OnPlayButtonClicked()
{
    Play();
}

public void Play()
{
    sequence.Clear();
    sequence=TranslateCodeFromBlocks(canvas_.transform, sequence);
    
    if (sequence.Any(item => item.ID == "Function"))
    {
        // Code to execute if an item with ID="Function" is found
        Debug.Log("Found an item with ID='Function' in the sequence");
        loop2 = new MainLoop(mainTarget, insideFunction, animator);
        StartCoroutine(loop2.Play());
        
    }
    else
    {
        // Code to execute if no item with ID="Function" is found
        Debug.Log("No item with ID='Function' found in the sequence");
        loop1 = new MainLoop(mainTarget, sequence, animator);
        StartCoroutine(loop1.Play());
        
    }
      
}

   public MainLoop(Rigidbody2D mainTarget, List<Function_> sequence_,AnimationManager animator)
   {
       this.mainTarget = mainTarget;
       this.sequence_ = sequence_;
       this.animator = animator;       
   }

   public IEnumerator Play()
   {
       foreach (Function_ fun in this.sequence_)
       {
           fun.Func(animator, mainTarget);
           BoxCollider2D mainTargetCollider;
           mainTargetCollider = mainTarget.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
           
           animator.Move();
           yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
}
```

I did try to put an `if/else` statement in th  for each loop and a stop loop if there was no element left in the sequence. But it did not work for both `coroutine`. The system only reads one `coroutine` and stops there, even though there are still some items in sequence.

`foreach (var item in sequence)
{
Debug.Log("Item"+item);

```
    if (sequence.Any(item => item.ID == "Function"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Found an item with ID='Function' in the sequence");
        loop2 = new MainLoop(mainTarget, insideFunction, animator);
        StartCoroutine(loop2.Play());
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log($"No item with ID='Function' found in the sequence. Item ID: {item.ID}");
        loop1 = new MainLoop(mainTarget, sequence, animator);
        StartCoroutine(loop1.Play());
    }
```

}`

Comment: I feel we are missing some implementation details .. what is `MainLoop` and sequence etc?

Comment: well, you can have 2 variables 1 per coroutine, and you can use those to tell a b it about whether the coroutine is running or not.. however, please [mcve] as this is confusing

Comment: Can you enlighten me more about 2 variables per coroutine? Meaning, in my case, i can assign loop1 and loop2 under same coroutine? (I already edit the code. I'm sorry if my code is hard to understand ><)